# 50-synaptics.config file missing

Tags: mouse

I recently switched from Ubuntu to elementary OS and my right click on my laptop doesn't work. I used to solve this in Ubuntu by editing the 50-syaptics.config file. I would like to edit the 50-syaptics.config file to enable right click but I can not find it in elementary OS.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to locate the file using `apt-file` (check the spelling though, I'm sure it's "synaptics" and not "syaptics") and then install the according package. Try that first, because without the according drivers, the driver settings in that file are useless.

However, that's still just a configuration file which is loaded as one of many from a directory. The "50-" gives that away, it is used to control the order of loading. So, you could just as well create your own file with the according settings or the settings could be present in any other file already, waiting for you to edit them.

Answer (score 0):

if you have the driver installed...check inside

```
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/
```

if you need the driver, then check again

```
$ sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```